# How to achieve this flexbile layout using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to achieve this layout with flexbox, that each element automatically takes up the space and slides in the empty space?

[see this image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anzf9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#main {
  flex: 10;
}

#left {
  flex: 3;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.left-box {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #7f7f7f;
}

.right-box {
  height: 400px;
  background: #42664d;
}

.big-box {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="left-box">
      Left Box
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      Left Box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    <div class="big-box">Big Box</div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```